# Sum(count()) for last four months individually?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find out tot(count) values with months for last 4 months individually how I can do this

table stucture was

```
CREATE TABLE `lime_survey_16579` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`submitdate` datetime default NULL, 
`lastpage` int(11) default NULL, 
`startlanguage` varchar(20) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`token` varchar(36) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL, 
`16579X10X31` varchar(5) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULLPRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=480 ;
```

here $survey = lime_survey_16579 
and $temp= 16579X10X31 
here 16579X10X31 has values like A1 A2 A3 ..

How I can do this to give output like

```
tot month 

2 july 
4 aug 
6 sep 
9 oct
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below for all data:

```
SELECT count(id) as tot, MONTHNAME(submitdate) as `month`
FROM lime_survey_16579
GROUP BY month(submitdate) 
ORDER BY month(submitdate)
```

To limit the data to last 4 month, please try below:

```
SELECT count(id) as tot, MONTHNAME(submitdate) as `month`
FROM lime_survey_16579
GROUP BY month(submitdate) 
ORDER BY month(submitdate) DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Sel's solution is not going to work if you have data going into the previous year.  Presumably, you want only the most recent "jul" record, not the sum of all of them.

For this, you can do:

```
SELECT count(id) as tot, MONTHNAME(submitdate) as `month`
FROM lime_survey_16579
GROUP BY monthname(submitdate), year(submitdate)
ORDER BY min(submitdate) DESC
LIMIT 4
```

You could optionally put the year on the SELECT line as well.

I replaced the `month(submitdate)` in the `group by` and `order by` clauses with other expressions.  This avoids using a MySQL (mis) feature called *hidden column*, where columns not mentioned in `group by` clause and not aggregated are allowed in the `select` clause.  Other SQL engines (as well as the standard) do not permit this.